# How to eliminate all the spaces in a list of numbers (front and back) but keep one in between the numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have a list of numbers like this

```
  -4.4987000e-01  -2.0049000e-01  -4.8729000e-01  -6.1085000e-02  -5.1024000e-02  -2.1653000e-02   3.0788000e-01  -5.7097000e-02  -1.5610000e-02   1.3241000e-01   3.6023000e-01   2.0951000e-01  -4.4486000e-04   4.5643000e-02   2.1099000e-01   5.5061000e-01   1.8639000e-01   5.8702000e-02   1.8000000e+01  -5.1000000e+01   2.9000000e+01   4.4000000e+01  -2.5000000e+01   2.0000000e+01  -7.8000000e+01  -4.0000000e+00  -5.7000000e+01   5.4868000e-03  -4.8718000e-03   3.1912000e-03   5.2027000e-05   3.4499000e-04   2.5141000e-03  -2.0454000e-04  -1.9931000e-03  -6.1825000e-04   2.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   3.5905000e-02  -1.0375000e+02  -1.1897000e+02   1.5385000e+02  -6.2466000e+01   2.0804000e+02   4.4696000e+00  -4.6665000e+01   1.4479000e+02  -2.5231000e+01  -2.0513000e+02  -4.0358000e+01   9.2609000e+01   8.8504000e+00   6.1909000e+01   6.9962000e+01   9.1949000e+01  -2.0233000e+02  -1.5710000e+01  -5.6219000e+01  -1.3258000e+01   2.3295000e+02  -2.5827000e+02   5.7025000e+01   6.0528000e+01   6.1473000e+01   5.5480000e+00   5.1505000e+01   2.9502000e+01  -2.0039000e+02   9.6260000e+00   4.4402000e+01   7.5328000e+01   3.3595000e+00   5.0048000e+01   5.8790000e+01  -2.7963000e+02   8.7446000e+01   2.9345000e+01  -6.6092000e+00  -1.6112000e+00   1.6497000e+02  -3.3687000e+01   1.7421000e+02  -1.4319000e+02   1.3931000e+02  -1.4961000e+02   1.6481000e+02  -1.7286000e+02  -1.8169000e+02  -1.7561000e+02  -1.7869000e+01  -1.3961000e+01  -9.2109000e+00   4.5912000e+00   2.3210000e+01   1.4623000e+02  -1.7808000e+02   1.5201000e+02  -1.2972000e+02   1.2648000e+02  -1.4733000e+02   1.6865000e+02   1.8033000e+02
  -5.2843000e-01  -2.5912000e-01  -4.2584000e-01  -6.1339000e-02  -7.5853000e-02  -2.7442000e-02   3.0166000e-01  -6.4007000e-02  -4.2905000e-02   3.3057000e-01   2.3707000e-01   3.6533000e-01   6.5008000e-03   5.2863000e-02   2.2453000e-01   5.4726000e-01   1.7977000e-01   8.5435000e-02   2.5000000e+01  -2.3000000e+01   2.8000000e+01   4.6000000e+01  -5.4000000e+01   3.9000000e+01  -7.8000000e+01  -2.0000000e+00  -6.8000000e+01   7.6492000e-03  -4.4639000e-03   2.4742000e-03   7.4460000e-04  -6.5452000e-06   2.5198000e-03  -3.8057000e-04  -1.9782000e-03  -1.0207000e-03   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   3.3818000e-02  -7.9480000e+01  -7.4092000e+01   2.6918000e+02  -6.4591000e+00  -1.8279000e+02   7.5153000e+01  -4.4098000e+01   1.4419000e+02  -4.2769000e+00  -1.7227000e+02  -2.5832000e+01  -2.9895000e+01   6.0674000e+01   1.3823000e+02   5.6429000e+01   6.4801000e+01  -2.6334000e+02   3.4945000e+01   3.9544000e+01   4.4425000e+01   7.3094000e+01  -2.4618000e+02   5.5202000e+01  -4.3122000e+00  -3.5971000e+01  -4.0005000e+01   2.4211000e+02  -3.0704000e+01  -1.8313000e+02  -1.7990000e+00  -2.8792000e+01   2.9179000e+02  -1.7592000e+01  -7.4246000e+01  -1.7671000e+01  -2.2706000e+02   4.1538000e+01   2.5262000e+01   1.1633000e+02   2.7411000e+01   1.8463000e+00  -3.3862000e+01   1.7156000e+02  -1.4708000e+02   1.5506000e+02  -1.7217000e+02   1.8060000e+02  -1.7751000e+02   1.7789000e+02  -1.5722000e+02   1.2871000e+00  -4.9295000e+01  -2.8774000e+01   9.7736000e+00  -4.6825000e+00   1.0302000e+02  -1.8273000e+02   1.6897000e+02  -1.5129000e+02   1.2489000e+02  -1.1842000e+02   1.2541000e+02   2.0331000e+02
  -4.9823000e-01  -2.6346000e-01  -4.0683000e-01  -5.0683000e-02  -6.6742000e-02  -2.4397000e-02   2.7500000e-01  -1.3061000e-01  -1.0567000e-01   2.8596000e-01   3.3375000e-01   2.6932000e-01   1.0920000e-02   5.4195000e-02   2.1799000e-01   5.4572000e-01   1.3984000e-01   1.1345000e-02   2.6000000e+01  -2.4000000e+01   2.9000000e+01   6.0000000e+01  -3.9000000e+01   4.2000000e+01  -7.8000000e+01  -3.0000000e+00  -6.7000000e+01   8.9250000e-03  -5.8038000e-03   2.7718000e-03   5.8406000e-04  -5.7379000e-05   2.4386000e-03  -6.5300000e-04  -2.4464000e-03  -8.5056000e-04   1.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.0957000e-02  -3.4940000e+01   1.9048000e+02  -1.2839000e+00  -2.6178000e+02  -3.8176000e+01   1.7091000e+02  -1.8192000e+01  -2.1046000e+01  -9.3653000e+01  -7.2957000e+01  -6.8327000e+01  -2.0539000e+00   2.2286000e+01   1.7142000e+02   3.9634000e+01   9.8349000e+01  -2.9960000e+02   6.2743000e+01  -1.7442000e+01   6.9406000e+01   9.1777000e+01  -2.5362000e+02   5.6482000e+01   1.0460000e+01   3.5242000e+01   8.3919000e+01   2.4787000e+00   1.6242000e+01  -2.1568000e+02   3.5917000e+01  -3.1472000e+01   2.4643000e+02  -6.7954000e+01  -4.5022000e+00   2.4380000e+01  -2.4936000e+02   5.4252000e+01   3.9900000e+01   6.1425000e+01   3.6881000e+01   1.0403000e+00   2.4462000e+01   1.7538000e+02  -1.4825000e+02   1.4900000e+02  -1.6719000e+02   1.7977000e+02  -1.8226000e+02   1.8268000e+02  -1.7823000e+02  -6.6030000e+01   2.1203000e+01  -5.1797000e+01   3.8823000e+01  -5.3340000e+01   1.6133000e+02  -1.8005000e+02   1.5152000e+02  -1.2785000e+02   1.1796000e+02  -1.2576000e+02   1.3976000e+02   1.9323000e+02
```

As you can see, it starts with 2 spaces. It's going to have 2 spaces if the next number has a negative sign and 3 spaces if it doesn't. I want it so that it starts with a number then comma seperated like this:

```
-4.9823000e-01,-2.6346000e-01,-4.0683000e-01,-5.0683000e-02
```

I tried variations of this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as data:
     plaintext = data.read()
     plaintext = plaintext.replace('   ', ',' )
     plaintext = plaintext.replace('  ', ',' )
```

But can't figure out the best way to solve this.

edit-

This is the [source][1] of the numbers
I edited the list of numbers. As you can see if starts a NEW line after  1.8033000e+02,  2.0331000e+02, and  1.9323000e+02 . I looked through the data to  see if it had the new line `\n` but it didn't and that's throwing me off. I need to put each row as a row in a CSV file. How would I make it so that it accounts for new line when adding to the CSV file?

```
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as data:
        plaintext = data.read()
        plaintext = plaintext.split();
        plaintext = ','.join(plaintext)
        with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            csv_file.write(plaintext)
```

This code will put everything in 1 row in the CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .split() to split it by whitespace and then .join to put it back together and put commas in between the numbers:

```
plaintext = data.read()
plaintext = ','.join(plaintext.split())
```

If you want to seperate the code by newlines first to make a 2D array for a csv file, that is fine also:

```
plaintext = data.read()
plaintext = [i.split() for i in plaintext.split('\n')]
```

To write it into the csv:

```
import csv
with open(<yourfile>, 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(plaintext)
```

Answer (score 2):

Split on space, join with a comma:

```
  data = "-4.9823000e-01  -2.6346000e-01  -4.0683000e-01   5.0683000e-02  -6.6742000e-02"
  parsed_data = ",".join(data.split())
  # -4.9823000e-01,-2.6346000e-01,-4.0683000e-01,5.0683000e-02,-6.6742000e-02
```

**UPDATE**: Since you're reading from a file with new lines and you want to keep the lines just read the file line by line, perform the same procedure and write it out in the new file:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f_in, open("file.csv", "w") as f_out:  # open the files
    for line in f_in:  # read the input file line by line
        f_out.write(",".join(data.split()) + "\n")  # 'convert' and write to the output file
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `regex` to replace multiple spaces with a single `,` :

```
plaintext = data.read()
plaintext = re.sub(r"\s+", lambda m: ',', plaintext, flags=re.M)
```

**Example**:

```
s = "-4.9823000e-01  -2.6346000e-01  -4.0683000e-01  -5.0683000e-02"
print(re.sub(r"\s+", lambda m: ',', s, flags=re.M))
# -4.9823000e-01,-2.6346000e-01,-4.0683000e-01,-5.0683000e-02
```

Comment: I have edited my question as that code is putting all the data into 1 row in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

I am confused why your csv row doesn't end with '\n'.

Anyway, you can use `readline()`

```
newText=''
while True:
    plainText=data.readline()
    if plainText=='':
        break
    newText+=','.join(data.split())+'\n'
```